# Update tracks on board to reflect new design rules - Kicad

Tags: pcb-design, kicad, design-rules

A PCB has been laid out with track widths according to a set of design rules by net class.

I have modified the net class design rules (`Setup` → `Design Rules...` → `Net Class Editor`) and now I wish to update the tracks on the PCB to reflect their new values. How do I do that?

Answer (score 13):

In Kicad 5, this can be done with the `Edit` → `Edit All Tracks and Vias...` dialog.

[image: v5.0.0-rc2 Edit All Tracks and Vias dialog]

Choose `Set all tracks and vias to their netclass values` and click `OK`.

From this dialog, you can also set to the net class values on a per-net basis, and you can update only the track width, or only the via size.

Comment: This sort-of works: It doesn't work for tracks and vias that cannot expand if they are in between two components that are close together.